# using are to name but a few

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, formality

In a very formal writing style,

Is it fine to use *to name but a few* in a separate sentence?

> There are a lot of algorithms to do hashing. MD5, SHA1 and CRC are to name but a few.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to leave out "are" and put a comma after CRC.

- . . . hashing. MD5, SHA1 and CRC, to name but a few.

another way would be to swap like this:

- . . . hashing; to name but a few, MD5, SHA1 and CRC.

(For a bit more punch, you could substitute an em-dash for the period or semicolon above, respectively.)

Comment: do you mean this? `. . . hashing— MD5, SHA1 and CRC, to name but a few`

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. But no spaces around the em-dash.